# Inserting into a Huffman Tree

Tags: c, insert, linked-list, huffman-code

I am having problems with my huffman tree; when I try to build it I get the nodes in the wrong place. For example, I want my node of weight 2 (with children i:1 and n:1) to go in between a node of m:2 and space:3 but instead it goes right after the previous node that I put in (2 with children of e:1 and g:1).

My question is: how do I insert a node with two children into a huffman tree (I am using a linked list) by priority of both it's weight (aka the sum of both its children) and the symbols of the children (i.e. the right child 'n' comes before the other right child of 'g').

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: also, how can I print off the codes of the tree in alphabetical order; right now I have them printing off by rightmost tree to leftmost

Here is my insert function...

```
    struct node* insert(struct node* head, struct node* temp)

    {

    struct node* previous = NULL;

    struct node* current = head;



     printf("entering insert function\n");



    // finds the previous node, where we want to insert new node

   while (temp->freq > current->freq && current->next != NULL)

  {

     printf("traversing: tempfreq is %lu and currentfreq is %lu\n", temp->freq, current->freq);
     previous = current;

    current = current->next;

   }

   if (current->next == NULL)

   {

    printf("hit end of list\n");

    temp = current->next;

   }

  else

  {

printf("inserting into list\n");

temp->next = current;

previous->next = temp;

  }  

  return head;

 }
```

Comment: Regarding your additional question: In the tree, the alphabetical ordering is gone. If you want to create a table of codes in alphabetical order, create an unordered array of a structure that contains the code and the encoded letter and then sort that table by letter. Alternatively, create an array that covers all possible letters (but possibly more, ideally all ASCII characters) and initialise their Huffman codes to `""` or null. Then write the Huffman codes to the respective field as you traverse the tree. Then scan the array and print it, skipping any null entries.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? Would I want to add an array to my struct that I already have?

Comment: You need a separate data structure alongside your Huffman tree. You could, for example, add a char buffer to your node structure that contains the code as 0 and 1 characters. Then you create a linear array of pointers to (existing) nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the insertion wrong when you hit the end of the list. This:

```
temp = current->next;
```

should be the other way round, otherwise you just assign `NULL` to a temporary variable, which won't do anything to your list.

But I think that you also got your special cases wrong. The special case is not "insert at the end", but "insert a new head". Your code will fail if `head == NULL`. (This might not happen, because you have already a list of nodes without children and you remove nodes until only one node is left, but still.)

A better implementation might therefore be:

```
struct node *insert(struct node *head, struct node *temp)
{
    struct node *previous = NULL;
    struct node *current = head;

    while (current && temp->freq > current->freq) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (previous == NULL) {
        temp->next = head;
        return temp;
    }

    temp->next = current;
    previous->next = temp;

    return head;
}
```

Note how this code never derefeneces `current` or `previous` when they are `NULL`. Your special case "insert at the end" is handled by the regular code when `current == NULL`.

**Edit**: Concerning your request to print the nodes in alphabetical order: There are many possibilities to do that. One is to add a char buffer to your structure that contains the encoding for the letter:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    unsigned long freq;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char code[32];
};
```

Then you create an "alphabet", i.e a list of 256 pointers to nodes of your Huffman tree, initially all null. (You'll need that alphabet for encoding anyways.)

```
struct node *alpha[256] = {NULL};
```

Then traverse your tree, pass a temporary char buffer and assign nodes to your alphabet as appropriate:

```
void traverse(struct node *n, int level, char buf[], struct node *alpha[])
{
    if (n == NULL) return;

    if (n->value) {
        alpha[n->value] = n;
        strcpy(n->code, buf);
    } else {
        buf[level] = '0';
        traverse(n->left, level + 1, buf, alpha);
        buf[level] = '1';
        traverse(n->right, level + 1, buf, alpha);
    }
}
```

When the node has a value, i.e. is childless, the value (ASCII code) is assigned to the alphabet, so that `alpha['a']` points to the node with value `'a'`. Note that the alphabet does not create nodes, it points to existing nodes.

Finally, print the alphabet:

```
char buf[32];
traverse(head, 0, buf, alphabet);

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (alpha[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%c: %s\n", alpha[i]->value, alpha[i]->code);
    }
}
```

Please note that 32 is n arbitrary value that is chosen to be high enough for the example. In a real tree, memory for the code might be allocated separately.

Comment: Thank you! This still doesn't work however when two of the nodes have the same frequency but temp's rightmost symbol is greater than current's rightmost symbol. The all just insert like temp->next = current & previous->next = temp;

Comment: This code never looks at the child nodes, only at the frequency stored directly at this node. I don't think that you need the information on the child nodes for a Huffman tree. Whether "a" is encoded as 0100 and "s" as 0101 or the other way round doesn't matter if their frequencies are equal.

Comment: For the assignment the node that gets priority is the one whose right child is bigger

Comment: @user3366369: You can change the `>` to `>=`. Because the current node is made up from children whose frequency is at least as big as all other child frequencies already sorted into the list, that should work without explicitly looking at the child node. (If you were to do that, you'd also have to check whether both nodes you compare actually _have_ children in oder not to derefenece a null pointer.)